# Is there a standard name for this 2 look PLL algorithm?

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

I'm currently learning 2-look PLL and came across [this PDF](https://www.cubeskills.com/uploads/pdf/tutorials/4-look-last-layer.pdf) with some algorithms. I went through and gave names to the algorithms just so they'd be easier to remember and refer to, but got stuck on this one for corner permutation:

[image]

I've seen this referred to as Y-perm on various sites, but a lot of Y-perms I've seen swap the corners as well as 2 edges, but this one only swaps corners

Algorithmically it looks more like an [N-perm](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/PLL#N_Permutation_:_b), but that also has edge swapping...

Does this algorithm have a standard name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name for this algorithm is the Nb-perm.

However, the PDF ignores the edges in that step because it's using 4 look instead. Swapping the edges comes afterward when all 4 corners are in position; except for a final U-turn which is skipped until the 4th step.